Is it possible to run autograd backward one node at a time?
Let say I have a complex model with many many layers.
When I obtain the output of the model I calculate the loss.
Now when I run loss.backward() it would calculate gradients for all layers at once.
But is it possible to run backward() one layer at a time?
So what I'm trying to do is to obtain gradients for layer 1 first, pass them to optimizer, and then immediately set grads to None in order to free the memory. Then move on to calculate gradients for the layer 2, and so on until it reaches the final layer using a loop. Is this possible?
Edit: added a toy example to demonstrate the problem. for complexity I also used an architecture that somewhat resembles unet, ie output of layer 1 may be used in layer 2 but also in layer 3
import torch
from torch.optim.optimizer import Optimizer, _use_grad_for_differentiable

class NeuralNetwork(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flatten = torch.nn.Flatten()
        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Linear(5, 5)
        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Linear(5, 5)
        self.layer3 = torch.nn.Linear(5, 5)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.flatten(x)
        layer1_out = self.layer1(x)
        layer2_out = self.layer2(layer1_out)
        return self.layer3(layer2_out + layer1_out)

class OptimS(Optimizer):
    def __init__(self, params=None, lr=1e-3):
        super().__init__(params, dict(lr=lr,differentiable=False,))
    
    @_use_grad_for_differentiable
    def step(self, closure=None):
        for group in self.param_groups:
            for param in group["params"]:
                param.add_(param.grad, alpha=-group['lr'])

model = NeuralNetwork()
batch, labels= torch.randn((5,5)), torch.randn((5,5))
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()

paramteres =model.parameters()
optimizer = OptimS(paramteres)
out = model(batch)

loss = criterion(out,labels) /2
loss.backward()

optimizer.step()
optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)

# you realize optimizer step is doing a just doing a loop,
# so we could also run it per layer, something like:

out = model(batch)
loss = criterion(out,labels) /2
loss.backward()

def layerwise_optimizer_step(param, lr=1e-3):
    param.add_(param.grad, alpha=-lr)
    param.grad = None

for param in paramteres:
    layerwise_optimizer_step(param, 1e-3)

# so the goal is to create some custom backward function,
# that upon calculating the gradinet for each layer would 
# pass the corresponding parameter to our layerwise optimizer


Can you please include a self-contained [MCVE] with wich we can discuss it? Furthermore, could you elaborate what the goal is in the end? You mentioned saving memory, but is this your primary goal or do you intend to achieve something else?

yup, the goal is to save memory so that only few gradients are stored in memory at a time and immediately passed to our layerwise optimizer as soon as they are obtained

The related concept I believe is "gradient checkpoint." You can check out this repository, where the author not only provides code verification but also a detailed explanation of the method. (I can't write it better than the author did, lol, so I'm just leaving a comment.).

The models in question already support gradient checkpoint, but all the gradients are still stored in memory first before it is passed to optimizer.

As I remember the gradients are computed during loss.backward call and not optimizer step. Anyway I would recomment to check this notebook from Sebastian Rachka on gradients checkpoints: https://github.com/rasbt/deeplearning-models/blob/master/pytorch_ipynb/mechanics/gradient-checkpointing-nin.ipynb

I don't think what you want is possible. It would require changing both the core autograd process and the backward method of all ops involved. Whatever you hope to accomplish there are simpler ways to achieve it

What you're trying to implement sounds very similar to what LightningAI does. You could probably find a reference implementation in their repository.

TLDR

Copy the code at the end, run it, follow code comments
...but I think the motivation behind this solution would help

TLDR how it's done:

Use a backward hook to call the optimizer immediately after a gradient was generated, then clear said gradient
PyTorch's register_post_accumulate_grad_hook function allows you to hook into the right location

Introduction

Now when I run loss.backward() it would calculate gradients for all layers at once.

This is not true. loss.backward() calculates gradients layer by layer, starting from the loss layer
and going backwards through the network, each gradient is dependent on the previous layer's gradient.

But is it possible to run backward() one layer at a time?

That's what the backpropagation kind of does.

So what I'm trying to do is to obtain gradients for layer 1 first, pass them to optimizer,
And then immediately set grads to None in order to free the memory.

It is not possible, as for you to obtain gradients for layer 1,
you need to calculate gradients for all layers after it before (layer3 -> layer2 -> layer1 in
your case).
You could use other algorithm than backpropagation, for example Forward Forward,
with some implementations available (here or
here), please note this approach was tested only on small networks,
and it is a research topic.
See other possible alternatives here.
How PyTorch's backward() conceptually works?
Actual backward() process is more complex, this is a simplified description:

After calling backward() on a torch.tensor (loss in this case),
an implicit torch.tensor(torch.ones_like(tensor) is created
and used as an actual starting gradient for the backward() process.
Tensors grad_fn attribute is called (if it is not None!)  with the gradient tensor(s)
which calculates the gradient of an operation with respect to the input tensors.
This one is multiplied with the gradient from layer above (according to the chain rule).
tensor.grad_fn.next_functions is used to find next nodes in the computational graph, which are
grad_fn themselves
Repeat steps 2-4 until you reach the leaf tensors (which have grad_fn=None).
Save the gradients in the tensor.grad attribute.

Now, the very important thing is that backward() will clear the intermediate gradients (unless you
specify retain_graph=True), hence you cannot save memory here.

Only gradients in the leaf nodes are saved (e.g. model.layer3.weight.grad will not be None, but out.grad will be),
the rest is aggressively cleared.

To verify, you can check the out.grad_fn after calling loss.backward()
(you should get a warning + None as a result).
Additional Resources

backward() should have as many inputs as there were outputs
for each operation in the chain. Same thing happens for grad_fn(), which calculates a single step
Extending PyTorch (specifically autograd) here
for more information
PyTorch hooks for autograd used later (thanks @Green绿色!)

Possible improvements + implementation
I think the only place where you could (realistically) save memory is when the gradients on the leaf nodes are set,
one could use PyTorch's register_post_accumulate_grad_hook
which will simply run after the .grad field was computed. PyTorch's backward hooks are explained in a bit more detail this helpful article from the PyTorch documentation.
In order to do that, one has to obtain gradient of a given layer, apply the correction
to the weights, and then set the .grad field to None.
An example SGD optimizer with this feature could look like this (please read code comments!):
class SGD:
    # You could specify additional parameters, different optimizers etc.
    # This one is a very basic implementation only for demonstration purposes
    # See [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/sgd.html#SGD)
    # for PyTorch's original implementation
    def __init__(self, lr: float = 3e-4, *debug_modules: torch.nn.Module):
        self.lr = lr
        # Debug modules are used to verify that only one module has gradient set to None
        # at any given time, see __call__ below
        self.debug_modules = debug_modules

    def __call__(self, param: torch.Tensor) -> None:
        if self.debug_modules:
            # Assert every module has gradient set to None
            # EXCEPT THE CURRENT ONE
            # You could also print the layers to see for yourself
            assert (
                sum([module.weight.grad is not None for module in self.debug_modules])
                == 1
            )
        param.add_(param.grad, alpha=-self.lr)
        # Clear the gradient immediately after the update
        param.grad = None

Here is how one could register it for your neural network (please read code comments!):
model = NeuralNetwork()

# Used 20 so one could see the difference in weights easily
sgd = SGD(20, *[c for c in model.children() if isinstance(c, torch.nn.Linear)])

# Register the hook for every linear layer
for module in model.children():
    if isinstance(module, torch.nn.Linear):
        module.weight.register_post_accumulate_grad_hook(sgd)

Full code
Full code I used so you could test it yourself:
import torch

torch.manual_seed(0)


class NeuralNetwork(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flatten = torch.nn.Flatten()
        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Linear(5, 5)
        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Linear(5, 5)
        self.layer3 = torch.nn.Linear(5, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.flatten(x)
        layer1_out = self.layer1(x)
        layer2_out = self.layer2(layer1_out)
        return self.layer3(layer2_out + layer1_out)


class SGD:
    # You could specify additional parameters, different optimizers etc.
    # This one is a very basic implementation only for demonstration purposes
    # See [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/sgd.html#SGD)
    # for PyTorch's original implementation
    def __init__(self, lr: float = 3e-4, *debug_modules: torch.nn.Module):
        self.lr = lr
        # Debug modules are used to verify that only one module has gradient set to None
        # at any given time, see __call__ below
        self.debug_modules = debug_modules

    def __call__(self, param: torch.Tensor) -> None:
        if self.debug_modules:
            # Assert every module has gradient set to None
            # EXCEPT THE CURRENT ONE
            # You could also print the layers to see for yourself
            assert (
                sum([module.weight.grad is not None for module in self.debug_modules])
                == 1
            )
        param.add_(param.grad, alpha=-self.lr)
        # Clear the gradient immediately after the update
        param.grad = None


model = NeuralNetwork()

# Used 20 so one could see the difference in weights easily
sgd = SGD(20, *[c for c in model.children() if isinstance(c, torch.nn.Linear)])

# Register the hook for every linear layer
for module in model.children():
    if isinstance(module, torch.nn.Linear):
        module.weight.register_post_accumulate_grad_hook(sgd)

batch, labels = torch.randn((5, 5)), torch.randn((5, 5))
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()

out = model(batch)

loss = criterion(out, labels) / 2

# Now calling backward on the loss suffices
print(model.layer1.weight)
loss.backward()
print(model.layer1.weight)

Please note:

Difference in the weights (as expected)
Assert is passing, meaning only one layer has gradient set to None at any given time
One could implement different optimizers this way (too much for a SO post though)
You don't have to modify the model source code, smarter registering would be possible
Didn't test for performance at all


Regarding autograd backward hooks, the PyTorch documentation contains this very helpful article.

Ok, I've edited your answer to include the article on backward hooks. I think the reference to Lightning AI doesn't quite fit here -- and it's also not really detailed enough for an own answer. It should be fine as-is. Besides, I also took the freedom to add more qualified information into your TLDR, hope it's ok.

Yes, it is possible but it is not a standard approach and may require some manual intervention. The typical way PyTorch handles gradients is by computing them all at once with loss.backward(). You can achieve what you're asking for by manually controlling the computation graph and gradients.
first a Forward Pass then a Layer-by-Layer Backward Pass


I guess the crucial detail that should be added in order to receive upvotes rather than downvotes is showing in code how the layer-by-layer backward pass has to be implemented.
